# В окне iframe нужно открыть php код

Tags: php, html, iframe

Добрый вечер. Пишу сайт, страницы которого перелистываются слайдером; в каждый слайд вклеена соответствующая html-страничка с помощью iframe.
Сейчас мне нужно добавить php-страницу. Но iframe не хочет ее интерпретировать внутри фрейма
Вот кусок кода:
.

```
...
<div>
  <h2 class="title">Карта звездного неба</h2> 
  <iframe src="sky.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>

<div>
  <h2 class="title">Телепрограмма</h2>
  <iframe src="/php/bd_progr.php" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

вопрос такой - как сделать так, чтобы содержание .php файла точно так же появлялось в слайдере - а  не в отдельном окне? если с фреймом это сделать невозможно, то можно как-то иначе.. вроде возможно через скрытые div, но как конкретно - я не знаю. Очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Comment: а вообще php код выполняется если отдельно запустить страницу которую вы пытаетесь в ифрейм вставить?

Comment: да, конечно. если по этому адресу пройти, всё работает

Comment: попробуйте прописать не относительный путь, а фиксированный с указанием урла сайта . К примеру "http://example.com/php/bd_progr.php"
Вместо example.com вставьте свой урл.

Comment: нет, не получается. А вообще - это реально? чтобы содержимое php страницы появлялось подобным образом? внутри окна?

Comment: Что выводит в ифрейме вместо требуемой страницы (bd_progr.php) ?

Answer (score 1):

Уверяю вас, что интерпретатору все равно откуда идет запрос.

Как правило для того что бы страница **не** открывалась в iframe действительно нужно приложить усилия.

Так что скорее всего вы не там ищете, либо пытаетесь стянуть страницу с другого сайта.
Где догадались заглушить открытие через iframe (делается это обычно посредством JavaScript или заголовком HTTP).

---

UPD:

Из-за бурления в комментариях поясняю:

Имелось ввиду, что **интерпретатор в любом случае обработает страницу**

И не открыться  может только если она со стороннего сайта и там заглушили её встраивание в iframe  «посредством JavaScript или заголовком HTTP»

P.S.  «не открыться» - значит мы увидим что угодно (редирект, пустую страницу…)

и заметьте не слова о исходниках

Comment: нет, страница с моего сайта) 
пожалуйста, расскажиет подробнее про заглушки. как выглядит эта часть кода?

Comment: в.htaccess это прописывается например. (чтобы не интерпретировался)

@Gedweb вы действительно считаете что есть в мире идиот который предпочитает публиковать в iframe исходники вместо запуска ?

Comment: Господин @eicto имеет ввиду что если бы PHP не обрабатывал код, который клиент запрашивает для iframe, то простой строчкой `<iframe src="http://facebook.com/login"></iframe>` мы бы увидели что у FB под "капотом" что само по себе полная глупость, тк PHP наплевать для каких целей интерпретировать то что внутри `<?php ?>`